# Links within refreshing div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm following the example below to continuously refresh a div with a mysql table.

http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

I'm using the complete and timeout parameter of ajax to refresh the div instead of using setinterval and settimeout.

The problem I'm having is that the returning data can include links and these are not working when clicked. I believe the problem could be that the div is constantly refreshing and thus I the click is ignored. How do you allow links within a refreshing div? It works with setinveral and settimeout but I want to use long polling to allow real time updates.

Here is my code.

```
// get page url variables
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

// set var for parent id to scroll to
var tid = getUrlVars()["tid"];  
var pid = getUrlVars()["pid"];

(function poll(){

    // get latest page
    $.ajax({  
        url: "ajax.tickets_details.php?tid=" + tid,
        type: 'GET',  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html) {

            // print results from get in div
            $("#ticket_updates").html( html );

        }, 
        complete: poll,
        timeout: 30000

    });

})();
```

Thanks!

Comment: "The problem I'm having is that the returning data can include links and these are not working when clicked." Could you specify in what way they are *not working* ? Do they successfully get transformed into an anchor tag and become clickable?

Comment: They are formatted as links and are clickable but don't follow the href.

Comment: How does the links look when they are returned? Can you debug your script and copy a returned link and post it here as well?

Comment: The links would work without the ajax complete function. I can't copy the returning link because the element is refreshing every second and I can't get to the code.

Comment: your polling wrong. This will refresh the page constantly (with no gap). Use [SetTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to poll every x seconds instead and it should become more responsive.

Comment: Yes, that's the point (*near real time*) when does the browser have chance to process the click of the link? The link will disappear before, after or during the click event.

Comment: Thanks. I've used timeout before but wanted to use the best method.

Comment: this isn't the best method. I've highlighted fundermental flaws in my answer below. Don't believe everything you read on the internet :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just read that tutorial and it's based on false information.

this tutorial says:

> This means our poll function won't get called again until both the
>   ajax call is complete and (at-least) thirty (30) seconds have passed.

this isn't true. If your request returns in < 30s **it will fire again immediately**, thus causing your problem. The Actual definition of timeout is:

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override
>   any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts
>   at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in
>   progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible
>   for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and
>   below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the
>   request times out; accessing any object members may throw an
>   exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be
>   cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after
>   the timeout period.

So this means if the request takes more than 30s it will cancel the waiting handler **only** (not the call itself, this will continue but the javascript handler will go out of scope).

There is even a comment highlighting this flaw:
[image]

I'd find a new tutorial as that one appears to be talking nonesense. This technique is not doing "server push" at all. Only web sockets can push from the server. HTTP 1.1 does not support any server push methods at all.

Comment: Much appreciated. The example given doesn't work for me but I've added setTimout(function,30000) to the bottom of my function to repeat.